# How to set SelectManyCheckbox title dynamically JSF2

Tags: jsf-2

Is there any way to set selectManyCheckbox title dynamically ? In title I want to show Item name .

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox id="sType" value="#{studentBean.optionalsubjects}" converter="subjectConverter" required="true">
   <f:selectItems value="#{subjectBean.oplist}" var="sType" itemLabel="#{sType.detail}" itemDescription="#{sType.detail}" />
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

Comment: I don't get it. What do you mean with "title"? The labels of the checkboxes in your example are already dynamic.

Comment: in selectManyCheckBox there is **title** attribute which will show title at mouse over .I want to show user Optional Subject code when they mouseover it( Check box) .Hope this makes clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this won't work with `h:selectManyCheckbox` since the title attribute is the same for all select items.

You could try javascript like the [jquery tooltip plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/tooltip) in order to attach tooltips on client side.